# MySQL not able to use backtick for reserved keyword

Tags: mysql, keyword, backticks, reserved

I'm creating a simple table and i'm not able to use the reserved keyword Password. I tried using backticks, but get an error

> ```
> "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near '`'."
> ```

I don't wanna use double quotes, can someone please tell me how to get this backtick thing working.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    NTID                VARCHAR(20)         PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName           VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    MiddleI             CHAR(1),
    LastName            VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    EmailAddress        VARCHAR(100)        UNIQUE,
    `Password`          VARCHAR(50)     
);
```

Comment: Another clue that you are not using MySQL: `UNIQUE` cannot be placed inline with a column. The `UNIQUE KEY` syntax is supported by MySQL only as a table-level constraint.

Answer (score 6):

reading your error message, it seems that you are using SQL Server, not MySQL.

You need to use `[]` to escape reserved keywords.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    NTID                VARCHAR(20)         PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName           VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    MiddleI             CHAR(1),
    LastName            VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    EmailAddress        VARCHAR(100)        UNIQUE,
    [Password]          VARCHAR(50)     
);
```